# Vue md-able not sorting Timestap

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to sort a `timestamp` column and a column that contains an `array` using `Vue.js`. Please use the following link to review the: [demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-material-multiple-forked-jltd9?file=/App.vue).

I want to sort the columns with the names: `pos` and `Timestamp`. Is there a default function that may be called to do this? If not, how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `object.sort()` method to achieve what you want. I have updated your code here: [UPDATED SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-material-multiple-forked-swk5z)

Following changes have been made to your code:

a `toggles` property in the data method:

```
toggles: {
    t: false,
    /* you can add all property keys here, which you wish to sort */
},
```

and `toggleSort` method:

```
toggleSort(property) {
  /* get toggle status for the property */
  const alreadyToggled = this.toggles[property];

  /* sort users array accordingly */
  this.users.sort((a, b) =>
    alreadyToggled ? a[property] > b[property] : a[property] < b[property]
  );

  /* update toggle status for the property */
  this.toggles[property] = !alreadyToggled;
}
```

then on `@click` you can toggle on the basis of your desired property:

```
<Button @click="toggleSort('t')">
  Sort Timestamp {{ toggles['t'] ? "Asc" : "Desc" }}
</Button>
```

For sorting `t`, you can use `@click('t')`, for `pos` property, you can use `@click('pos')`. So on and so forth. Just make sure, you add all these keys to be sorted in the `toggles` object as well.